# Fast way to get mean values of rows accordingly to subscripts

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, mean

I have a data, which may be simulated in the following way:

```
N = 10^6;%10^8;
K = 10^4;%10^6; 

subs = randi([1 K],N,1);
M = [randn(N,5) subs];
M(M<-1.2) = nan;
```

In other words, it is a matrix, where the last row is subscripts.
Now I want to calculate `nanmean()` for each subscript. Also I want to save number of rows for each subscript. I have a 'dummy' code for this:

```
uniqueSubs = unique(M(:,6));
avM = nan(numel(uniqueSubs),6);
for iSub = 1:numel(uniqueSubs)
    tmpM = M(M(:,6)==uniqueSubs(iSub),1:5);
    avM(iSub,:) = [nanmean(tmpM,1) size(tmpM,1)];
end
```

The problem is, that it is too slow. I want it to work for `N = 10^8` and `K = 10^6` (see commented part in the definition of these variables.

How can I find the mean of the data in a faster way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect job for [`findgroups`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) and [`splitapply`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html).

```
% Find groups in the final column
G = findgroups(M(:,6));
% function to apply per group
fcn = @(group) [mean(group, 1, 'omitnan'), size(group, 1)];
% Use splitapply to apply fcn to each group in M(:,1:5)
result = splitapply(fcn, M(:, 1:5), G);
% Check
assert(isequaln(result, avM));
```

Comment: Note: I've used the `'omitnan'` version of `mean` because that exists in base MATLAB and does exactly the same thing.

Comment: A lot more readable than my loop for sure, but some 15% slower; is that because `findgroups` and/or `splitapply` do under the hood checks, which I omit in my loop?

Comment: I'm not sure where the additional overhead comes from to be honest. `findgroups` and `splitapply` are both MATLAB code, and on my machine there's no obvious egregious wastage in either. I think I prefer the readability of `findgroups` and `splitapply`, and (now that I've learnt them) I think more people should take advantage of them.

Comment: I agree with you there. The difference is not that large as to be an issue and the names of the functions are very descriptive, making them much more readable than a for-loop with self-chosen variable names.

Answer (score 5):

```
M = sortrows(M,6); % sort the data per subscript
IDX = diff(M(:,6)); % find where the subscript changes
tmp = find(IDX);
tmp = [0 ;tmp;size(M,1)]; % add start and end of data
for iSub= 2:numel(tmp)
    % Calculate the mean over just a single subscript, store in iSub-1
    avM2(iSub-1,:) = [nanmean(M(tmp(iSub-1)+1:tmp(iSub),1:5),1) tmp(iSub)-tmp(iSub-1)];tmp(iSub-1)];
end
```

This is some 60 times faster than your original code on my computer. The speed-up mainly comes from presorting the data and then finding all locations where the subscript changes. That way you do not have to traverse the full array each time to find the correct subscripts, but rather you only check what's necessary each iteration. You thus calculate the mean over ~100 rows, instead of first having to check in 1,000,000 rows whether each row is needed that iteration or not.

Thus: in the original you check `numel(uniqueSubs)`, 10,000 in this case, whether all `N`, 1,000,000 here, numbers belong to a certain category, which results in 10^12 checks. The proposed code sorts the rows (sorting is `NlogN`, thus 6,000,000 here), and then loop once over the full array without additional checks.

---

For completion, here is the original code, along with my version, and it shows the two are the same:

```
N = 10^6;%10^8;
K = 10^4;%10^6; 

subs = randi([1 K],N,1);
M = [randn(N,5) subs];
M(M<-1.2) = nan;

uniqueSubs = unique(M(:,6));
%% zlon's original code
avM = nan(numel(uniqueSubs),7); % add the subscript for comparison later
tic
uniqueSubs = unique(M(:,6));
for iSub = 1:numel(uniqueSubs)
    tmpM = M(M(:,6)==uniqueSubs(iSub),1:5);
    avM(iSub,:) = [nanmean(tmpM,1) size(tmpM,1) uniqueSubs(iSub)];
end
toc
%%%%% End of zlon's code
avM = sortrows(avM,7); % Sort for comparison

%% Start of Adriaan's code
avM2 = nan(numel(uniqueSubs),6);
tic
M = sortrows(M,6);
IDX = diff(M(:,6));
tmp = find(IDX);
tmp = [0 ;tmp;size(M,1)];
for iSub = 2:numel(tmp)
    avM2(iSub-1,:) = [nanmean(M(tmp(iSub-1)+1:tmp(iSub),1:5),1) tmp(iSub)-tmp(iSub-1)];
end
toc %tic/toc should not be used for accurate timing, this is just for order of magnitude
%%%% End of Adriaan's code

all(avM(:,1:6) == avM2) % Do the comparison
% End of script

% Output
Elapsed time is 58.561347 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.843124 seconds. % ~70 times faster

ans =

  1×6 logical array

   1   1   1   1   1   1 % i.e. the matrices are equal to one another
```

Comment: That's because your code's output is beyond understanding! First of all, there's no declaration for `iSub`, but i presume that it would be `ii`. It returns a `numel(tmp)*6`matrix! What are these rows and columns supposed to be means? Kindly explain!

Comment: @Rahul thanks for catching the typo, I corrected it to match the OP's code. The declaration for `avM` I copied from the original code, what the columns mean you should as him, I just improved the speed of his code. The first five columns give a mean of the elements on a certain subscript, and the sixth column gives you how many elements had that corresponding subscript. If you also want to know which subscript it was, well, it's simply indexed `1:numel(rows)`, so the row number is the subscript. Let me know if you need more information.